# Problem using mpiexec with python and mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py, mpiexec

I have a PC with Linux OpenSuse Leap 15.3.
I use python through Anaconda version 4.11.0.
I have mpi4py installed but when I want to run a simple program like:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD 
print("%d of %d" % (comm.Get_rank(), comm.Get_size()))
```

and I run the program using:

mpiexec -n 4 python3.8 nameofprogram.py

I get the following error:

Invalid error code (-2) (error ring index 127 invalid)

INTERNAL ERROR: invalid error code fffffffe (Ring Index out of range) in MPID_nem_tcp_init:373

Fatal error in PMPI_Init_thread: Other MPI error, error stack:

MPIR_Init_thread(586)..............:

MPID_Init(224).....................: channel initialization failed

MPIDI_CH3_Init(105)................:

MPID_nem_init(324).................:

MPID_nem_tcp_init(175).............:

MPID_nem_tcp_get_business_card(401):

MPID_nem_tcp_init(373).............: gethostbyname failed, localhost.localdomain (errno 1)

I have googled and this same problem has been reported other times, but I have not been able to get an answer that I can understand to solve the problem. Please, could someone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear. English is not my native language. I will try to explain myself better. The program does not run. I don't know why. 
I run in a console the following command:
mpiexec -n 4 python3.8 nameofprogram.py
And as a response I get the error message that I have placed in the question.
What I want is to know why the program does not run and if it is possible to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running it as `mpiexec -n 4 python3.8 nameofprogram.py` try to run it as `mpiexec -n 4 python3 nameofprogram.py`

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I am very grateful to you